# How can I fix an error in a Quasar Application when I using LangChain's CharacterTextSplitter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, openai-api, langchain

I have the a Quasar application using  2.3 that is using the latest build of OpenAI (4.10) that is giving me an error if I try use LangChain's Textloader I'm also using node 16+

```
    import { TextLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/text";
    import { CharacterTextSplitter } from "langchain/text_splitter";


    const loader = new TextLoader("..../../.")
    const docs = await loader.load();
```

I get

```
     text.js:48 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: readFile is not a function
     at TextLoader.load (text.js:48:26)
     at async Proxy.storeData (IndexPageLangChain.vue:75:16)
```

not sure if it can't find my file- so I used in internal path and a full url to check but got the same error.

The basic application works but I'm trying to add functionality but so many of the AI components keep making breaking changes with new releases.

Comment: `readFile` is a Node API for reading files from local file systems, not meant for the browser.  I'm not familiar with langchain or openai but the error implies that it's meant for server-side only use.  Running this code client-side in a browser is not possible.  This code is meant for a backend which you can build separately and integrate with your frontend.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How would I build it separately ? Do you happen to have a link I can check out.  Could I make Quasar a SSR application?

Comment: I found one-- thanks   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkIGAqAP1GY&t=760s